# <jdoc:include type ="component" /> doesn't work

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I have taken an empty template and in the index.php enter the code for displaying articles .. in the video tutorial everything is displayed correctly but nothing is displayed for me

If I set the default template as default everything works fine. I have linked everything together (article with category, category with menu) and activated but nothing is shown. When I code normal html everything is displayed to me.

```
...
<body class="<?php echo (($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) ? ('front') : ('site')).' '.$active->alias.' '.$pageclass; ?>">


  <h1>Hello</h1>
 <hr />
    <jdoc:include type ="component" />
 <hr />
```

Am i wrong? Because in the tutorial its working with the same code

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

```
<jdoc:include type ="component" />
```

Remove the space between type and = , like so:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Like in HTML, there can never be space between a attribute and its value.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, then it would be more appropriate to close the question as an Off-topic typo.